# Masonry and Infinite Scroll and Google DFP Advertising Callback

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am hoping that someone can help me. I am using the Google DFP Ad Server to serve some ads on my website. I am also using Infinite Scroll and Masonry.

I am using the JQuery DFP Script https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js/blob/master/jquery.dfp.js
to serve the DFP ads. I am trying to get the adds to display in infinite scroll but the ad does not get triggered.

I have created the following script file to accommodate the call back, on the masonry load of the page...

The script below calls the (Google Analytics Script)  into the pages generated by infinite scroll

```
`function (newElements) {
    infscrPageview++;
     (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),  =s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');ga('send', {  'hitType': 'pageview',  'page': window.location + infscrPageview +'/',  'title': 'category/page/' + infscrPageview});`
```

and this part activate the social media buttons...

```
var el = document.getElementById('.rtsocial-container');
    if (typeof gapi !== "undefined") {
        gapi.plusone.go(el);
    }
    if (typeof FB !== "undefined") {
        FB.XFBML.parse(el);
        /*FB.XFBML.parse();*/
    }
    if (typeof twttr !== "undefined") {
        twttr.widgets.load();
    }
    $container.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
    });
```

How will I create the callback/append function to activate the DFP ads in the infinite scroll page?

Any help will be appreciated!

You can view the page http://3d-car-shows.com/category/motorcycle/ where I am creating the implementation!

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the solution added this line `$.dfp('xxxxxx');` to the script above... just below

```
if 
    (typeof twttr !== "undefined") {
            twttr.widgets.load();
        }
```

and in the jquery.dfp.js file I have set the value `enableSingleRequest: false,` from true to false and now it works 100%

Hope this will help someone with similar issues!